# How to filter and unfilter in Pandas Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv that I want to parse. 
one of the step require changing value of a particular row based on the value of another row.

the only way I know (i'm a newb with python) is to do pandas filter, it works great.

the question that I cant seem to find the answer is, how do I then unfilter it so I can do another filter?

Here's my working code for now

I have tried crawling pandas reference guide but i cant seem to find the answer.

```
import pandas as pd
from prompt_toolkit import prompt

filename = input("Enter the path of excel file = ")
abc = pd.read_csv(filename, header=1, dtype=str)

abc = abc[(abc['column_title_A'].str.startswith("300")) | (abc['column_title_A'].str.startswith("860"))]

# change value based on another value in another
abc.loc[abc['column_title_B'] == '29JUL2019', 'column_title_C'] = '15/02/2019'
abc.loc[abc['column_title_B'] == '25FEB2019', 'column_title_C'] = '19/05/2019'

# from here on, how do I unfilter the above to apply another filter below?
abc = abc[(abc['column_title_B'].str.startswith("300")) | (abc['column_title_B'].str.startswith("860"))]
```

i want the to filter sets of A and then unfilter to do another filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than replace abc, you can use a mask:

```
mask = (abc['column_title_A'].str.startswith("300")) | (abc['column_title_A'].str.startswith("860"))

# change value based on another value in another
abc.loc[mask & (abc['column_title_B'] == '29JUL2019'), 'column_title_C'] = '15/02/2019'
abc.loc[mask & (abc['column_title_B'] == '25FEB2019'), 'column_title_C'] = '19/05/2019'

mask = abc[(abc['column_title_B'].str.startswith("300")) | (abc['column_title_B'].str.startswith("860"))]
...
```

Comment: +1 thanks very much, with the modificataion you supplied, I was able to achieve what I wanted. appreciate your reply here!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "unfilter", you should not filter and overwrite at the first place.

I would suggest to go like this:

```
# filter Admsn_ctr_crs_cd to only show 300XXXX for UG or PG 860XXXX
selector = abc['column_title_A'].str.startswith("300") | abc['column_title_A'].str.startswith("860")

# change value based on another value in another
abc.loc[(abc['column_title_B'] == '29JUL2019') & selector, 'column_title_C'] = '15/02/2019'
abc.loc[(abc['column_title_B'] == '25FEB2019') & selector, 'column_title_C'] = '19/05/2019'

# from here on, how do I unfilter the above to apply another filter below?
selector = abc['column_title_B'].str.startswith("300") | abc['column_title_B'].str.startswith("860")
abc.loc[otherselector & selector, "column_title_D"] = "foo"
```